# How to upload video file to AWS in background?

Tags: ios, swift, video, background-process

I have query regarding Uploading videos in Background like whats app in swift .shall we use Background identifier or any ideas?

Comment: use **uploadTasK** in **URLSession** and dont forget to enable the **background mode** in capabilities

Comment: are you uploading the file 100% right without background support?

Comment: for e.g see this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-3-upload-3a5be9a69950) and [this](https://blog.newrelic.com/engineering/ios9-background-execution/)

Answer (score 0):

Use alamofire for this. For Almofire read [Tutorial](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)

Video will be sent as stream of data. Convert the video to data then send to server with this function.

```
//This function will send the stream of data to server.

    let videoData = Data() //you need proper video data here.
    let url = URL.init(string: "URL to upload")  //place your valid url here.

    Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(videoData, withName: "video", fileName: "video.mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")

    }, to: url!, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    print("SUCCESS\n\n", JSON)
                } else {
                    print("FAILED\n\n", response)
                }
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    })
```

Comment: how will you handle this one in inactive and suspend state